# Issue with qTip2

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I have 10 divs. Each one has an attribute `data-tooltip="text here"`.

I would something like:

```
$('.my_div').qtip({
      content: $(this).attr('data-tooltip'),'bottom middle'
      },
      style: {
         tip: true,
         classes: 'ui-tooltip-red'
      }
    });
```

But it doesn't work. How can I get the tooltip text for each div without writing ten times the code with `.qtip` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to loop with [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) instead.

Something like this:

```
$('.my_div').each(function(){
    $(this).qtip({
        content: $(this).attr('data-tooltip'),
        style: {
            tip: true,
            classes: 'ui-tooltip-red'
        }
    });
});
```